# Problem numbering chapter, sections

Tags: sectioning, chapters, intersections

I'm trying to write something in LaTeX, I would change the style of my paragraph numbering.

I would have this:

> ** My PDF **
>
> My Chapter I
>
> My section 1
>
> My section 2

To do so, I put this code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt] {report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}
\section { My section}
\section { My section }

\end{document}
```

but instead of the previous example, I get this:

> ** My PDF **
>
> My Chapter I
>
> My section I.1
>
> My section I.2

Can someone explain me?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard `section` appearance takes also a value from `chapter` counter. Hence you should also add:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```